# Variable inner types for wrapped Repa array

Tags: haskell, existential-type, repa

I'm attempting to write a thin wrapper around [repa](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/repa) to provide extra constraints for some domain-specific work I'm doing. I have the type:

```
newtype Tile p r a = Tile { _array :: Array r DIM2 a }
```

where `Array` comes from `repa`. I'd like to hide the `r` because it adds noise to type signatures and makes `Tile` a leaky abstraction:

```
newtype Tile p a = Tile { _array :: Array ? DIM2 a }  -- what should `?` be?
```

Unfortunately, that `r` can change between repa operations. Most of the time it's `D` (for "delayed representation"), but when the data is first created from a list or vector it would be `U` ("unboxed vector") or `V` ("boxed vector"). These are used as type hints to help repa optimize its operations.

Is there a way for me to hide the `r` as I'd like, but allow it to vary naturally internally without affecting typechecking with my wrapper `Tile` type? Is this the domain of `RankNTypes` and friends? I'll admit I don't understand them very well. To be the most clear, I'd like to be able to write:

`foo :: Tile p a -> Tile p b -> Tile p c`

where the two `Tile` arguments contain (for instance) an `Array U DIM2 Int` and `Array D DIM2 Int` respectively. Is this a bad thing to desire?

Comment: You'll have to use an actual `data` declaration, but you can do `data Tile p a = forall d. Tile { _array :: Array d Dim2 a }`.

Comment: That's closer to what I need, yeah. But woops, turns out that `d` has some typeclass constraints elsewhere :S

Comment: You can also put the constraints in the `data` declaration. `data Showable= forall a. Show a => SomeShow a`.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get around the issue by forcing the wrapped `Array` to always contain the `D` type param by using the [`delay` function](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/repa-3.4.1.2/docs/Data-Array-Repa.html#v:delay).

This also allowed me to keep `Tile` as a `newtype` and also define a `Functor` instance for it.